# Is there a similar thing to a JAR file in C++?

Tags: java, c++, jar, cmd

The question may sound a little vague, but I wasn't sure how else to phrase it. I was wondering if you could make a `C++` file that was similar to a `JAR` file (so it runs independently of eclipse/cmd). I was also wondering if there is a similar thing to a Frame/JFrame in `C++`. Not a problem here, I am merely curious.

NOTE: I am a C++ noob, but have been programming in java for over a year.

Comment: First of all, C++ development is not platform independent in terms of library packaging, i.e., in Linux, your library are `.so` extension, while Windows are `.dll`.

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman, are .so and .dll mentioned in the C++ spec? If not, do you really think they are related to *C++* as a language?

Comment: @aioobe, they're not in the spec, but neither is packaging. I don't see how you would create a resource file that is as "independent" (since Windows packages them in a DLL file).

Comment: A typical C++ program, built by a typical C++ compiler _will_ run indepently of Eclipse and CMD.EXE. On Windows, a "console" (text) application will get a text window similar to CMD.EXE but without a `C:\` prompt (that prompt is from CMD.EXE)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Java code is translated into JAR which is bytecode which is translated in run-time to machine code. You can run this file on each platform.

C++ is translated to machine code at the time of compilation. You can't transport compiled executable between platforms. For each platform you need to compile source files again.

Comment: To be picky: You can't move jar files between platforms either, it only runs on the JVM. And *that* has to be recompiled for each host system.

Comment: This is actually not true. A JAR is not bytecode, it is just a Zip archive containing class files which contain the bytecode. A possible solution for C++ would be the Fat Binary concept (e.g. Apple's Universal Binary application bundle), this however has to be supported by the OS or by a launcher software.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: No, because C++ is not platform independent. Even if you use only standard library functions like the standard containers, the executable you create can not run on other systems, sometimes not even on other version of the *same* platform (Linux is known for this).

Comment: Longest answer: Noooooooooooo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. C++ is a platform independent programming language, which means that you can compile every simple program on every platform, as long as you don't use platform specific features. This means you *can compile* it on every platform. But that does not mean that your executable is cross-platform, like a Java JAR.

When you compile it, you create a native executable.
In Windows, it compiles to an `exe`. In Linux / OS X (unix) an extension-free file.

So, it depends on what you really want. (Since your question is a bit vague)

And if you are searching for a single cross-platform solution: the answer is **no**.
If you are searching for a way to make your application start without terminal: the answer is **yes**. (But I don't know how, since I never used Windows)

Comment: you mean `is NOT a platform independent..`?

Comment: If you compile some source code on Linux, even if it only uses functions from the standard library, you still can't run it on e.g. Windows or OSX. So no, there is nothing like jar-files for C++.

Comment: I have windows, so it's .exe files. Thing is, if I double click the .exe file in windows explorer, the cmd window pops up for a split second then immediately closes again (this is for my helloworld program

Comment: @JoachimPileborg,Nishant - No, I rephrased what I mean.

Comment: @imulsion that's because your program doesn't wait for the user to say "I'm done". Add something like `std::string dummy; std::cout << "Press enter to continue"; std::cin >> dummy;` and it will wait.